# Visual Studio 2022 not showing as a kit in VSC for cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, cmake, visual-studio-2022

ive never used C++ or Cmake before and I wanted to learn. i installed cmake and all the necassary extensions. i fund out that you needed a compiler/generator/builder i dont reaslly know the correct term. But i saw you can use visual studio 2022 as one. I already have it installed so i went to use it and its just not there, I have the workload installed on it too! i've seen lots of tutorials where its just there but mines not. Im so confused, I dont know if theres something im doing wrong.

here are some images (i dont have enough reputation to use them lol):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgXqz.png drop down where visual studio 2022 should be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OhEw.png picture of one of the extensions needed for cmake in vsc
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2kZs.png picture of one of the extensions needed for cmake in vsc
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a86Gj.png picture of one of the extensions needed for cmake in vsc
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViqK2.png workload needed for visual studio 2022 to work as a compiler/builder/generator thing

Comment: My advice is to use CMake + Visual Studio 2022 Community as the IDE (+ msvc compiler) instead of VSCode. Or if you didn't want the 5GB download size of Visual Studio installed on your PC you probably want to use msys2 to install MinGW and use VSCode

Comment: I assume you've tried the "scan for kits" option? See also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/kits.md

Comment: @drescherjm which package exactly? There seems to be hundred of different “MinGW” packages each with different purposes.

Comment: VSCode has official MinGW instructions here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) install MinGW using msys2 like the instructions tell you. I highly recommend using msys2 over any other install method because you get the latest MinGW compiler + you get a large collection of opensource software that can easily be installed via the `pacman` package manager that is part of msys2. This saves you from looking for compatible binaries or having to download source code and have to build all third party libs yourself.

Comment: "scan for kits" isn't a package. it's a command/action. You run that command/action to get the CMake Tools extension to scan your system for kits. It's possible that after re-scanning, it will find your Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is CMake tools in Visual Studio Installer.

After  CMake installed, there will be a CMake template project.

[image]

You could refer to the tutorial [CMake projects in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170) to learn  CMake project.

[image]